# Clearing form after submit

Tags: javascript

I want to clear text fields after submit. please help me :(

```
<form name ="client" id="client" method="POST" action="index.php"   >
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" >

        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value=""> <br />

        <label>surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido"> <br />

        <label>age</label>
        <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" > <br />

        <label>sex</label>
        <select name="peso" id="peso" > <br />
        <option>male</option>
        <option>female</option>
        </select>  <br />


        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value ="submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Firefox remembers form contents after page refresh. you could use javascript to manually set the value of each input to empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how you're handling the form submit, it's unclear the solution you need. However, here's something you can implement using jQuery for what you need.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  $(this).find("input[type=text], select").val("");
});
```

Comment: It adds cleard fields on table. I want to clear after action.

Answer (score 0):

well, if your page is refresh, fields should be cleaned by themself, if the page is not refreshed, you can use javascript `document.getElementById('nombre').value = "";`for example

Answer (score 0):

This will reset your form (or other) after submit, including also other type of html inputs.

Hope this helps.

// usage

```
ResetFormControlValues('your form id')


function ResetFormControlValues(parent) {

    $(':input', '#' + parent)
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');
    $('input:radio', '#' + parent).removeAttr('checked');


}
```